# Network monitoring in windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-7, proxy, network-monitoring

Following image is the structure of my network
[image: My Network Diagram]

Now Internet is working fine

We want to monitor all the local ips using any tool in the gateway system (windows seven os)

- IP Connected to the Gateway
- Which URL they accessing
- Block Some Website like proxy server

is there any way to do the above list or any specific tool that can do all this

Suggest me

Thank You

Comment: my system acts like a router, i want all router features in system like mac filter, port forwarding etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pass-by filtering program can do what you want. Pass-by filtering program can be directly installed in the win7 gateway, it analyses network packets for monitoring and filtering.

Programs you can try:

1. WFilter Enterprise
2. Websense Enterprise